# How to install Win 2008 TS CAL on win server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, licensing

I just purchased 10 Windows Server 2008 CALs that I expected to install in my windows server 2003 machine. I received the emails from the vendor and Microsoft. I have an Authorization Number and License Number.

I go to Start > Programs > Administrative Tools > Terminal Server Licensing then right click on my server and click Install Licenses. After clicking Next once it tells me to type the license key pack ID in the boxes below. I don't have a license key pack ID!

What do I do and where do I get it? I have gone to Microsoft's Volume Licensing Center and looked under the product keys section but it tells me that no volume license keys were found.

Now what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. If you check out [this](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/downgrade-rights.aspx) link, it clearly states that 2003 downgrade rights come with 2008 licenses.

All I had to do was call Microsoft's activation line and they have me the key pack ID. Thanks for you help guys.

Comment: OK, I'm confused. Did you say that you just installed a Windows Server 2008 TS CAL pack on a Windows Server 2003 TS Licensing server? If so, how is that possible?

Comment: @joeqwerty - that is exactly right. Check out the link I gave in my post.

Comment: Right. I understand the downgrade rights issue. That's a legal thing. I'm referring to the fact that W2K8 TS CAL's need to be installed on a W2K8 TS Licensing server as a W2K8 TS can't communicate with a W2K3 TS Licensing server. Do you have a W2K8 TS? Have you run the licensing diagnostics tool on it? If so, what does it report?

Comment: @joeqwerty - No, I am not running a W2K8 Server anywhere. My original problem had to do with how to execute the downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

At least with true 2k3 CALs you got a letter where the license pack ID was at the top. You might need to go back to your vendor and request a downgrade license if you bought CALs with downgrade right.s

Comment: I understood from here http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/downgrade-rights.aspx that downgrade rights were included and that the the same key would work. The problem is that I don't have a key! Only an authorization number and license number.

Comment: @jeff you didn't get an authorization letter ... just the license number and authorization number?

Comment: I got an authorization letter as well.

Comment: If i'm remembering correctly the key pack ID is either in the top right, or buried in the first paragraph or two of the letter. I remember overlooking it 3 or 4 times last time I installed TS CALs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install 2008 TS CALs on a 2003 licensing server. They must be installed on a 2008 TS Licensing server.

You can however install your older 2003 CALs onto your new 2008 license server, so you don't have to keep running your old 2003 license server.

Comment: Dang it Chris. You beat me by 2 seconds. Curses!

Answer (score 1):

If these CAL's are for Terminal Services as you've stated in your title then the first step is to install a W2K8 server and install the Terminal Services Licensing role on it as a W2K3 TS license server can not issue TS CAL's for W2K8.